# Multiple sed operations on find -exec

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying to execute multiple sed operations on the find -exec operation. My code looks like this:

```
find . -name '*.html.haml' -exec sed -i '' 's/restaurant_id/company_id/g' && sed -i '' 's/restaurants/companies/g' && sed -i '' 's/restaurant/company/g' && sed -i '' 's/Restaurants/Companies/g' && sed -i '' 's/Restaurant/Company/g' "{}" \;
```

This seems not to work. How could I do that?

Error:

```
find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said, the problem is that the `&&` is interpereted to execute the sed command *after* the `find` command is finished, instead of passing one string of commands to be executed on each file.

The easiest way to achieve your desired result is to combine this all into one `sed` command with semicolons. Like so:

```
$ find . -name '*.html.haml' -exec sed -i 's/restaurant_id/company_id/g;s/restaurants/companies/g;s/restaurant/company/g;s/Restaurants/Companies/g;s/Restaurant/Company/g' "{}" \;
```

Comment: works like a charm. on mac os x i had to add the -i '' to make the command work.

Comment: @Hendrik. I'm glad it worked! What do you mean about adding the `i` flag, though? (Is there not already one there?)

Comment: for some reason you need to add -i "" on mac os X.

Answer (score 0):

The `&&`s will be interpreted by the shell. Quote them all to prevent this `'&&'`

You'll need to add `"{}"` to each sed command.

Alternatively you could use the `-e` option of sed to only execute sed once with multiple scripts.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to have multiple `ecex`s, like:

```
find . -name '*.html.haml' \
-exec sed -i '' 's/restaurant_id/company_id/g' "{}" \; \
-exec sed -i '' 's/restaurants/companies/g' "{}" \; \
-exec sed -i '' 's/restaurant/company/g' "{}" \; \
-exec sed -i '' 's/Restaurants/Companies/g' "{}" \; \
-exec sed -i '' 's/Restaurant/Company/g' "{}" \;
```

(though in this specific case a single `sed` is better, like accepted answer)

Answer (score -1):

your shell presumably splits this command to `find . -name '*.html.haml' -exec sed -i '' 's/restaurant_id/company_id/g'` and `&&` and `sed -i ...`

try quoting the exec command `find . -name '*.html.haml' -exec "sed -i '' 's/restaurant_id/company_id/g' && sed -i ..."`

another approach is an extern sed-script you can call with a single command from exec

Comment: Quoting the whole exec command will cause find to consider the whole command as an executable to run (including all the arguments), which will fail.