# perl script to add line of code only modifies one file

Tags: perl

I have this:

```
perl -pi -e 'print "code I want to insert\n" if $. == 2' *.php
```

which puts the line `code I want to insert` on the second line of the file, which is what I need done to every single PHP file

If I run it in a directory with both PHP files and non-PHP files it does the right thing, but only to one PHP file.  I thought `*.php` would apply it to all PHP files, but it doesn't do it.

How can I write it so it will modify every PHP file in a directory?  Bonus if there is an easy way to do this recursively through all directories. I don't mind running the Perl script for each directory as there aren't that many, but don't want to hand edit every single file.

Comment: Do you have to use perl [for that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985432/multiple-sed-operations-on-find-exec)? sed is really good at editing such things.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the file handle `ARGV` that Perl uses to read the files passed on the command line is never explicitly closed, so the line number `$.` just keeps incrementing after the end of the first file and never goes back to one.

Fix this by closing `ARGV` when it has reached end of file. Perl will reopen it to read the next file in the list, and so reset `$.`

```
perl -i -pe 'print "code I want to insert\n" if $. == 2; close ARGV if eof' *.php
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `sed`, this should work:

```
sed -si '2i\CODE YOU WANT TO INSERT' *.php
```

To do it recursively, you might try:

```
find -name '*.php' -execdir sed -si '2i\CODE YOU WANT TO INSERT' '{}' +
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`File::Find`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html).

Note, I've included 3 sanity checks to verify that things are actually being processed they way that you want.

1. Initially the script will just print out the found files until you comment out the bare return.
2. Then the script will save backups unless you uncomment the unlink statement.
3. Finally, the script will only process a single file until you comment out the `exit` statement.

These three checks are just so you can verify that everything is working as you desire before editing a whole directory tree.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;

my $to_insert = "code I want to insert\n";

find(sub {
    return unless -f && /\.php$/;

    print "Edit $File::Find::name\n";
    return; # Comment out once satisfied with found files

    local $^I = '.bak';
    local @ARGV = $_;
    while (<>) {
        print $to_insert if $. == 2 && $_ ne $to_insert;
        print;
    }
    # unlink "$_$^I"; # Uncomment to delete backups once certain that first file is processed correctly.

    exit; # Comment out once certain that first file is processed correctly 
}, '.')
```